# Synchronize files processing across cluster

Tags: java, multithreading, file, microservices

I run a cluster containing 2 or more instances of the same microservice.
Each of them access files on a shared data share, which in mounted as a local folder on both servers running microservices. Each file can be processed only once(in the entire cluster).
I want to have those files processed in parellel by nodes, so no file is being
more than once in the entire cluster.

Looking for idea how to solve it

I already thought about one node reading the files and putting their filenames into queue, so that nodes can read it from queue.

Also thought about synchronizing via database, where each node when trying to process file uses db to synchronize with other nodes.

Any idea how to solve it in a good manner?

Comment: Maybe this is a way for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38526966/how-best-to-file-lock-in-java-cluster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this might work:

```
String pathToFile = "/tmp/foo.txt";
try {
    Files.createFile(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(pathToFile + ".claimed"));
    processFile(pathToFile);
} catch (FileAlreadyExistsException e) {
    // some other app has already claimed "filename"
}
```

and you'll need these imports:

```
import java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
```

The idea is that each app instance agrees to work on any given file only if it is first able to create a `".claimed"` file in the same shared filesystem. This works because of behavior of `Files.createFile`:

> *Creates a new and empty file, failing if the file already exists. The check for the existence of the file and the creation of the new file if it does not exist are a single operation that is atomic with respect to all other filesystem activities that might affect the directory.*

(from this Javadoc:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createFile(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...) )